# Where does iptables log?

Tags: iptables, raspbian

I am trying to debug iptables as described here but it doesn't look like any logging is happening.

System is a Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59+ Kernel / Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch).

Any ideas as to why and how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The log are generated by the kernel and should appear as `kern.warning`: in Debian that goes to `/var/log/kern.log`.

However, iptables won't log anything by default. You must enable logging with `iptables -A INPUT -j LOG` or with some more specific rule.